# Why isn't 100% height and 100% width working in my ASPX page?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

The CSS and html alone work fine in a fiddle:

```css
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    min-height:600px;
    min-width:800px;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:0;padding:0;
}
html {overflow:auto;}

.fill {height:100%; width:100%; background-color:green;}

.flex-container {   
    display: flexbox; 
    display: -webkit-box;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
    display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
    display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
    display: -webkit-flex;     /* NEW - Chrome */
    display: flex;             /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */

}
.flex-1 {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
    -moz-box-flex: 1;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- */
    -webkit-flex: 1;          /* Chrome */
    -ms-flex: 1;              /* IE 10 */
    flex: 1;                  /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
}
.flex-column {
    flex-direction:column; 
    -webkit-flex-direction: column; 
    -webkit-box-orient:vertical; 
    -moz-box-orient: vertical; 
    box-orient: vertical;
    -moz-flex-direction:column;
    -ms-flex-direction:column;
}

.centering { margin: auto; }

.centre-form { width: 40%; max-width:400px; }

.content-padding {padding:2.5%;}

.profile-centre { width:70%; max-height:90% /*max-width: 1200px;*/}
.profile-box {width: 46.6%; /*max-width: 560px;*/ max-height:80%; background-color:white; padding-top: 0.8%; padding-left: 0.8%; padding-right: 0.8%;}
#lifestyle {height:80%;}
.profile-form {margin-right:5px; margin-left:auto; padding-right:3%;}
.profile-form-label {margin-right:0.8%}
.profile-text-box {width:50%;}
.profile-gender {width:25%; margin-right:25%;}
.profile-date {width:16.7%;}
.profile-slider {width:50%;}
.profile-slider-label {margin-right:1%;}

.create-centre {width:85%;}
.create-form {width: 50%;}
.create-form-inner{padding-right:30%; margin:0;}
.create-text-box {width:50%;}
.create-gender {width: 40%; margin-right: 10%;}
.create-date {width:16.7%;}
.create-lifestyle {width: 49%;}
.create-lifetyle-form {width: 95%;}

.statInput{width:10%};
.statGraphContainer{height:300px; width:100%;}
.statGraphSwap{cursor:pointer;}

.left-align {float:left;}
.right-align {float:right;}

.y-scroll-only {overflow-y:auto; overflow-x:hidden; }


.clearing {clear:both;}
.hidden {display:none;}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="div" class="fill" >Div</div>
</body>
```

however it does not work when included in my ASPX page, i have disabled and removed all other html content and javascript i previously added and the code behind file just contains an empty Page_Load method:

```css
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    min-height:600px;
    min-width:800px;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:0;padding:0;
}
html {overflow:auto;}

.fill {height:100%; width:100%; background-color:green;}

.flex-container {   
    display: flexbox; 
    display: -webkit-box;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
    display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
    display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
    display: -webkit-flex;     /* NEW - Chrome */
    display: flex;             /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */

}
.flex-1 {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
    -moz-box-flex: 1;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- */
    -webkit-flex: 1;          /* Chrome */
    -ms-flex: 1;              /* IE 10 */
    flex: 1;                  /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
}
.flex-column {
    flex-direction:column; 
    -webkit-flex-direction: column; 
    -webkit-box-orient:vertical; 
    -moz-box-orient: vertical; 
    box-orient: vertical;
    -moz-flex-direction:column;
    -ms-flex-direction:column;
}

.centering { margin: auto; }

.centre-form { width: 40%; max-width:400px; }

.content-padding {padding:2.5%;}

.profile-centre { width:70%; max-height:90% /*max-width: 1200px;*/}
.profile-box {width: 46.6%; /*max-width: 560px;*/ max-height:80%; background-color:white; padding-top: 0.8%; padding-left: 0.8%; padding-right: 0.8%;}
#lifestyle {height:80%;}
.profile-form {margin-right:5px; margin-left:auto; padding-right:3%;}
.profile-form-label {margin-right:0.8%}
.profile-text-box {width:50%;}
.profile-gender {width:25%; margin-right:25%;}
.profile-date {width:16.7%;}
.profile-slider {width:50%;}
.profile-slider-label {margin-right:1%;}

.create-centre {width:85%;}
.create-form {width: 50%;}
.create-form-inner{padding-right:30%; margin:0;}
.create-text-box {width:50%;}
.create-gender {width: 40%; margin-right: 10%;}
.create-date {width:16.7%;}
.create-lifestyle {width: 49%;}
.create-lifetyle-form {width: 95%;}

.statInput{width:10%};
.statGraphContainer{height:300px; width:100%;}
.statGraphSwap{cursor:pointer;}

.left-align {float:left;}
.right-align {float:right;}

.y-scroll-only {overflow-y:auto; overflow-x:hidden; }


.clearing {clear:both;}
.hidden {display:none;}
```

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head runat="server">
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"/>
        <title>Title</title>

        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
            <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
        </asp:PlaceHolder>

        <webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />
        <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />

    </head>
    <body>
        
        <form runat="server">
            <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true">
                <Scripts>
                    <%--To learn more about bundling scripts in ScriptManager see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=301884 --%>
                    <%--Framework Scripts--%>
                    <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Name="respond" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
                    <%--Site Scripts--%>
                </Scripts>
            </asp:ScriptManager>
            <div id="div" class="fill" >Div</div>
            
            

        
         
        </form>

        

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just for future reference it would make it easier for people to answer your question if you include the resultant HTML rather than the asp code. Please try to strip back the HTML and CSS down to just the bits relevant to your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that in your actual page `.fill` is contained within a `form`. This `form` has no `height` or `width` and is `display: block;` so it is taking up the full width of it's container (`body`) and using as much height as is required.

You have a couple of options:

- Move the `fill` class to the `form`
- Add `height: 100%;` to the `form` to ensure it takes up `100%` of the `body` `height`

**Simplified example:**

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 600px;
  min-width: 800px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html {
  overflow: auto;
}
form {
  height: 100%;
}
.fill {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <form runat="server">
      <div id="div" class="fill">Div</div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```